# powershell opens explorer window instead of launching the python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, environment-variables

In powershell session typing `python` opens a Windows Explorer window "How do you want to open this file?" to select the program to open this file.

However the same `python` command works as expected (launches interpreter) in cmd.

The same issue when specifying `python` with a `.py` script name.

Do I need to fix something in registry keys or file associations? Why only powershell is behaving badly, but cmd works as expected?

---

EDIT:

Just resolved the issue:

```
PS > (get-command python.exe).Path
C:\Python\Python35_64b\python.exe
PS > (get-command python).Path
C:\Python\Python35_64b\Scripts\python
```

Apparently I had a file `python` without extension somehow stuck in one of the paths in `%PATH%` environment variable. After deleting this dummy file (how it got there?!) everything works fine.

Maybe this post still may help someone in the future (possibly myself)!

---

Still the question here is why **cmd** and **powershell** have a different order of searching for files in `%PATH%` with and without extensions (`.exe`)?

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. If you want to share your answer, post a genuine answer. This allows others to quickly find solutions, and vote on them.

Comment: There is still a question at the bottom, so this post is to be continued..

Comment: CMD only finds an executes files without an extension if "." is in `PATHEXT`.

Comment: That's a different question (with undue assumptions). The command processor presumably evaluates the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable, where PowerShell doesn't.

Comment: @eryksun this is good to know. Is this a documented behavior? I could not find this anywhere.

Comment: CMD uses `PATHEXT` when searching the `PATH` directories and to check whether running files without an extension is allowed, given a "." entry. It always tries `CreateProcess` first before `ShellExecuteEx`, which ensures a proper execute permission check. PowerShell only calls `CreateProcess` if an extension is in `PATHEXT` (if the file isn't directly executable, it naively builds the commandline via `FindExecutable`, even if the first attempt failed due to a permission error) but without honoring the "." entry. Otherwise it always calls `ShellExecuteEx`, which ignores execute permission.

Comment: @eryksun if you can write an answer along these lines, I'm going to accept it!